# Nginx try_files config with redirect check for old URLs?

Tags: nginx

I've got a website that's had a few significant URL changes over the years and it's got loads of backlinks kicking around the web that I'd like to avoid 404s with.

Essentially the config needs to...

1. Check if the file exists
2. If not then check if it exists with a php extension
3. Still no file? Look at a php redirection handler file I've created (imagine  a big array that checks the url for a redirection match).
4. Still no match? Return a 404 with the right error page.

I can't get this chained logic to work with try_files. Here's my current config:

```
server {
listen 443;
server_name www.domain.co.uk;
root /var/www/domain.co.uk;
default_type text/html;
index index.php;

ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/domain.co.uk.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/domain.co.uk.key;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php @redirect-check;
}

location @extensionless-php {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php;
}

location @redirect-check {
    try_files @redirector =404;
}

location @redirector {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /redirection-check?request=$request_uri;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri @redirect-check;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

error_page  400 402 403 404 500 502 503 504 /error?error_type=$status;

}
```

Any help would be enormously appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement `try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php @redirect-check;` is invalid as the named location must be the last parameter. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details. But `@redirect-check` should be removed from the statement anyway, to perform step (2).

The statement `location @redirect-check { try_files @redirector =404; }` does nothing other than generate a 404 response. It should be deleted.

If you change `try_files $uri @redirect-check;` to `try_files $uri @redirector;` you should be getting close to your requirements.

Your `/redirection-check.php` script needs to respond with a 404 response to proceed to step (4). But you will need to add `fastcgi_intercept_errors on;` to allow the `error_page` directive to process response codes from the PHP scripts. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_intercept_errors) for details.

Answer (score 0):

All credit to @RichardSmith for pointing me in the right direction.

Here's what I ended up with which works well:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
}

location @redirector {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /redirection-check?request=$request_uri;
}

location @extensionless-php {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php;
}
```

Within redirection-check PHP it checks an array for a match on the $_GET['request'] and if matched, serves up the appropriate 301 redirect. If no match then it returns a 404.

Comment: One potential problem with `?request=$request_uri` is when the request URI contains a query string and therefore another `?`. You might consider using `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` instead of `$_GET['request']` which probably contains an identical value.